# Jquery group result of a selector in an array of array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-chosen

I have a random number of `select multiple` on my web page and when the user click on the send button, I retrieve the value of those `select multiple` through their `class`. I also use the chosen plug-in but I don't think it interfere with the issue I about to expose. Here is what my code looks like :

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="idName0" class="idName chosenSelect">
  <option value="...">...</option>...
</select>
<select multiple="multiple" id="idName1" class="idName chosenSelect">
  <option value="...">...</option>...
</select>
```

And to get the results :

```
results.push($(".idName").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
```

Let's say I have 2 `option`'s selected in the first `select` (with the `value` foo and bar) and one in the second one (with the `value` foobar). All this give me an `array` looking like :

```
[foo,bar,foobar]
```

What I want is :

```
[[foo,bar],[foobar]]
```

From what I know, when you call .val() on selector pointing to a `select multiple` in give you an array with the different selected `option`'s. And here, with multiple `select multiple` in the fray, I was hoping to create an array of those array.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` for this but you also need to wrap value of each `select` in array. If you don't want `null`'s in array for empty selects you can add `.filter(Boolean)` after `.get()`

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var data = $("select").map(function() {
    return [$(this).val()]
  }).get()

  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="idName0" class="idName chosenSelect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select multiple="multiple" id="idName1" class="idName chosenSelect">
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: By adding the [ ] in the return of the map function, everything works like I wanted ( $(".idName").map(function(){return [$(this).val()];}).get(); ). Thanks you.